# Changing a Parameter - who's responsible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, email, responsibility

I've got a table which gets filled by another application. This table contains an attribute called `IsMailSent`.

EF builds my objects of Type `Request` based on the database data.

The object looks something like this:

```
public class Request {
    int SomeInt;
    bool IsMailSent;
    SomeObject SomeObject;
}
```

Now I want to create a Service which will load all the entries with `IsMailSent == false` and send this mail to their recipients.

My current code works as follows:
A class called MailMessageService got a `Start()` and a `Stop()` method. The `Start` method looks like this:

```
public void Start(int delay) {
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        T = new Task(() => {
            MailService ms = new MailService(Res.ServerAddress, int.Parse(Res.ServerPort));
            while (true) {
                var messages = GetMailMessages(_context.Requests.Where(o => !o.IsMailSent));
                ms.Send(messages);
                Thread.Sleep(delay);
            }
        }, tokenSource.Token);
    }
```

The method `GetMailMessages` receives a Collection of `Request` and builds a Collection of `MailMessages`. Currently I created a class that inherits from `MailMessage` and contains a reference to the corresponding Request-object. The idea behind is that the `MailService` (which is responsible for sending the Mails) should set the `IsMailSent` property to `true`.

> So the `Send()` Method should set `IsMailSent = true`

But is this the best way to do it? As I understand the SOLID Principles, the `MailService` should not be responsible for setting this property (as it is responsible for sending the mails) - or am I wrong?

Comment: is the `IsMailSent` a property or a field?

Comment: I'ts a Property - setting it directly is just for ease to solve my (hopefully not opinion-based) issue. I have to admit that those Responsibility-questions are those that keep me awake ...

Comment: If this is the only mailsent application, it should set it to true. When multiple applications can send mails (server park), there should be an extra table for concurrency. (Like which application is processing what item)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a method for setting the `IsMailSent` to the `Request` class. So the `Request` class would finally decide to set or not set the `IsMailSent` to `true`. This way the set code is still in the `Request` class and it would still be possible to influence the set.

E.g.

```
public class Request {
    // Property
    public bool IsMailSent { get; private set; }

    public void MailSent() {
       // TODO check some conditions
       if (...) {
           ...
       }

       // If everything is correct set the property
       IsMailSent = true;
    }
}
```

And in the `MailService.Send(...)` you call `MailSent` method.

Comment: That looks fairly like my own solution - though the Request by itself can not decide if the mail has been sent I think the best solution is to set it when the Send() Method succeeded. Thank you :) +1